# How to use Latex with Matplotlib on Mac?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

This is the error:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found.
```

I have already installed MacTex. I also installed dvipng and ghostscript using Mac Ports, but it's still not working. I also tried pip install latex.

The exact same code can run on another linux computer, so it's not the problem of the code.

It outputs a blank figure while I am expecting a figure with plotted data.

Is there any way to solve this? Thank you so much!!!